# XMPPFrameWork didNotAuthenticate in Facebook

Tags: facebook, xmppframework, ios7, xcode5, facebook-sdk-3.0

I had been using a AppId, which is created in Facebook a few months ago for my **iOS chat application**. Now I have to use the newly created AppId for release.

If I am using the **old AppId** then the **XMPP** will **get authenticated** and able to chat with friends. While using the **new AppId**, XMPP is **not getting authenticated**. I tried many account logIns using both of this ids.
If any body has a solution, then please help me

```
<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```

Note:
I am using the latest XMPP Framework, which is updated a few hours ago (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).

Answer (score 0):

Chat API has been deprecated with the release of Platform API v2.0.
 Once version 1.0 is deprecated(April 30, 2015), chat.facebook.com will no longer be available.

Your old app is using API version 1.0 but all new apps are in API version 2.0 that's why your old appid is working and old app will work till April 30, 2015.
Version 1.0 will expire as scheduled on April 30, 2015.

For more details read Facebook Platform Changelog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/